# Installing opencv without root

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ubuntu

I'm trying to install opencv 2.4.11 without root permission. Following [this](https://gist.github.com/dynamicguy/3d1fce8dae65e765f7c4), here's what I've done so far:

```
# download opencv-2.4.11
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.4.11/opencv-2.4.11.zip
unzip opencv-2.4.11.zip
cd opencv-2.4.11
mkdir release
cd release

#compile and install
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D BUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB=ON -D INSTALL_TO_MANGLED_PATHS=ON -D INSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON -D INSTALL_TESTS=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON -D WITH_IMAGEIO=ON -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON ..
make all -j4 # 4 cores
make install
```

However, since I don't have root permissions, I set the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to my home folder: `/home/mixqui/raviteja/opencv`

How do I now configure opencv to work? How do I "make sure then that your compiler and linker know where OpenCV can be found", as mentioned in the comment [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/99965/how-to-install-opencv-for-python-without-sudo/)?

Edit: This is my `.bashrc` file. I've added the necessary changes to the environment variables. But it's still not working.

```
export PATH=/home/mixqui/raviteja/opencv:~/anaconda/bin:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:~/.local/lib:/home/mixqui/raviteja/opencv/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/mixqui/raviteja/opencv/lib/pkgconfig/:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Comment: You can simply run `make install` and then add the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`  path to your `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @LakshyaKejriwal I've made the changes to my environment variables. Still not working.

Comment: `sudo` is unnecessary if you don't want to write to a system directory, and will obviously fail if you lack the privilege. You want to take it out.

Comment: Yeah I actually didn't `sudo make install`. I did `make install`

Comment: @RaviTej310 what error are you getting after making changes to your `.bashrc` file?

Comment: I get this error: `>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
`